# Custom matcher in jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I'm trying to create a custom matcher in Jest similar to stringMatching but that accepts null values. However, the docs don't show how to reuse an existing matcher. So far, I've got something like this:

```
expect.extend({
    stringMatchingOrNull(received, argument) {
        if (received === null) {
            return {
                pass: true,
                message: () => 'String expected to be null.'
            };
        }

        expect(received).stringMatching(argument);
    }
});
```

I'm not sure this is the correct way to do it because I'm not returning anything when I call the stringMatching matcher (this was suggested [here](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2547#issuecomment-271573287)). When I try to use this matcher, I get: `expect.stringMatchingOrNull is not a function`, even if this is declared in the same test case:

```
expect(player).toMatchObject({
    playerName: expect.any(String),
    rank: expect.stringMatchingOrNull(/^[AD]$/i)
    [...]
});
```

Please, can somebody help me showing the correct way to do it?

I'm running the tests with Jest 20.0.4 and Node.js 7.8.0.

Comment: https://jest-bot.github.io/jest/docs/expect.html#expectextendmatchers explains it quite good

Answer (score 35):

There are two different kinds of methods that are related to `expect`. When you call `expect(value)` you get an object with *matchers* methods that you can use for various assertions (e.g. `toBe(value)`, `toMatchSnapshot()`). The other kind of methods are directly on `expect`, which are basically helper methods (`expect.extend(matchers)` is one of them).

With [`expect.extend(matchers)`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/expect.html#expectextendmatchers) you add the first kind of method. That means it's not available directly on `expect`, hence the error you got. You need to call it as follows:

```
expect(string).stringMatchingOrNull(regexp);
```

But when you call this you'll get another error.

```
TypeError: expect(...).stringMatching is not a function
```

This time you're trying to use use [`expect.stringMatching(regexp)`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/expect.html#expectstringmatchingregexp) as a matcher, but it is one of the helper methods on `expect`, which gives you a pseudo value that will be accepted as any string value that would match the regular expression. This allows you to use it like this:

```
expect(received).toEqual(expect.stringMatching(argument));
//     ^^^^^^^^          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//      string                   acts as a string
```

This assertion will only throw when it fails, that means when it's successful the function continues and nothing will be returned (`undefined`) and Jest will complain that you must return an object with `pass` and an optional `message`.

```
Unexpected return from a matcher function.
Matcher functions should return an object in the following format:
  {message?: string | function, pass: boolean}
'undefined' was returned
```

One last thing you need to consider, is using [`.not`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/expect.html#not) before the matcher. When `.not` is used, you also need to use `.not` in the assertion you make inside your custom matcher, otherwise it will fail incorrectly, when it should pass. Luckily, this is very simple as you have access to `this.isNot`.

```
expect.extend({
    stringMatchingOrNull(received, regexp) {
        if (received === null) {
            return {
                pass: true,
                message: () => 'String expected to be not null.'
            };
        }

        // `this.isNot` indicates whether the assertion was inverted with `.not`
        // which needs to be respected, otherwise it fails incorrectly.
        if (this.isNot) {
            expect(received).not.toEqual(expect.stringMatching(regexp));
        } else {
            expect(received).toEqual(expect.stringMatching(regexp));
        }

        // This point is reached when the above assertion was successful.
        // The test should therefore always pass, that means it needs to be
        // `true` when used normally, and `false` when `.not` was used.
        return { pass: !this.isNot }
    }
});
```

Note that the `message` is only shown when the assertion did not yield the correct result, so the last `return` does not need a message since it will always pass. The error messages can only occur above. You can see all possible test cases and the resulting error messages by [running this example on repl.it](https://repl.it/KO8l).

Comment: Oops! Thanks, @Michael, I forgot to write my intended usage of this matcher. I wanted to use it as a helper method inside the `toMatchObject` matcher. I've edited my question with the snippet that caused the error. From your answer, I assume using `expect.extend` is not the right way to do it. Are there any docs related to how to write helper functions for `expect` directly?

Comment: I don't think there is an official way to create such a helper method that is providing a pseudo value. You could try to define one yourself like [`StringMatching`](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/64f8dbc541494327d2f375a515c3e04a7ff8ac6a/packages/jest-matchers/src/asymmetric_matchers.js#L209-L232). Either way, a value being `null` is an indication of a bug. If you explicitly set it to `null` you should have separate tests that cover these scenarios to make sure that it is only ever `null` when you expect it. Testing for a value or `null` sounds like you squash multiple tests together.

Comment: @MichaelJungo how can I add my custom matcher to the second kind too, the helper methods called directly on expect? expect.extend() seems to only add it to the first kind, but the matchers available in the `jest-extended` package work directly on expect too, for example `expect(o).toEqual({ aNumber: expect.toBeWithin(1, 3) })`.

Comment: @MichaelJungo Do you need to check `this.isNot` in the first check for `null` to reverse it or when returning `pass: true`?

Answer (score 4):

I wrote this hack to use any of the `.to...` functions inside `.toEqual`, including custom functions added with `expect.extend`.

```
class SatisfiesMatcher {
  constructor(matcher, ...matcherArgs) {
    this.matcher = matcher
    this.matcherArgs = matcherArgs
  }
  asymmetricMatch(other) {
    expect(other)[this.matcher](...this.matcherArgs)
    return true
  }
}
expect.expect = (...args) => new SatisfiesMatcher(...args)
```

...

```
expect(anObject).toEqual({
  aSmallNumber: expect.expect('toBeLessThanOrEqual', 42)
})
```

Comment: please, add how to implement custom matcher class
// #script.test.js
expect(result).myCustomMatcherclass().method2();
// #myCustomMatcherclass.js
class myCustomMatcherclass {
  constructor() {...}
  method2(){...}
  method2(){...}
}