# How to test complex tree structure?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

Jasmine supports registering a [custom equality tester](https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/custom_equality). Is this possible in Jest? If not, how can I test the following:

```js
class Person {
  constructor(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }
}

// This API does not exist :(
expect.addCustomEqualityTester((first, second) => {
  if (first instanceof Person && second instanceof Person) {
    // Only name is important
    return first.name === second.name;
  }
});

// This array can be arbitrarily complex with many different objects and nestings.
// It's a tree structure.
expect(got).toEqual([
  new Person('Alice', 10),
  new Person('Bob', 20),
  new Foo(a, b, c),
  [
    new Person('Emma', 5),
    [x, y, z],
    new Person('Troy', 25),
  ],
]);
```

I understand I can use `expect.extend` to add a custom matcher *for a single object* but how would I use that in the above situation where the object schema is very dynamic?

There is a GitHub [issue](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/1751) requesting for a this exact API but it was closed without a solution for this problem, so now I'm just confused how this library is so popular and nobody has this problem. Maybe this is an XY problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom matcher in jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45743548/custom-matcher-in-jest)

Comment: No. I already mentioned I understand the `expect.extend` API but it doesn't work in this case because my custom matcher doesn't work with `toEqual` which does deep equality checks.

Comment: Your "where the object schema is very dynamic" exception sounds suspiciously like you want a matcher that can read your mind. The solution is obvious: you have to write a matcher that unwraps the passed value according to your custom logic, and it can only support comparisons that you are able to encode in javascript.

Comment: The snippet I provided works perfectly in Jasmine, but there is no equivalent API in Jest. Are you saying that I would have to implement something like `toEqualCustom` which does the same thing as `toEqual` except supports adding custom equality checks for certain objects it sees during the traversal?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by creating a new `toEqualCustom` matcher which does basically the same thing as the existing `toEqual` matcher except it supports passing in custom testers. The `equals` utility function available inside matchers supports custom testers.

```js
expect.extend({
  toEqualCustom(received, expected, customTesters) {
    const options = {
      comment: 'Deep object equality with custom equality testers',
      isNot: this.isNot,
      promise: this.promise,
    };

    const pass = this.equals(received, expected, customTesters);

    const message = () =>
      this.utils.matcherHint('toEqualCustom', undefined, undefined, options) +
      '\n\n' +
      `Expected: ${this.isNot ? 'not' : ''} ${this.utils.printExpected(expected)}\n` +
      `Received: ${this.utils.printReceived(received)}`;

    return {
      actual: received,
      message,
      pass,
    };
  },
});

function personNameTester(a, b) {
  if (a instanceof Person && b instanceof Person) {
    return a.name === b.name;
  }
}

expect(foo).toEqualCustom(bar, [personNameTester]);
```

However, an issue with this is the diff that is shown for a failing test won't always be correct.