# Call existing matcher from a Playwright custom matcher

Tags: typescript, testing, playwright

I'm adding a custom matcher to Playwright following [the documentation](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-advanced#add-custom-matchers-using-expectextend) about extending `expect`. Similar to this [unanswered discussion](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/discussions/14649), I'd like to call an existing matcher after massaging the input:

```
expect.extend({
  async toHaveDeploymentURL(page: Page, expected: string) {
    const fullyQualifiedPath = `https://deployments.company.com${expected}`;

    // This part doesn't work; call an existing matcher 
    return expect(page).toHaveURL(fullyQualifiedPath);
  },
});
```

I saw a [Jest issue](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/10329#issuecomment-820656061) with a hack to directly require the Jest matchers:

```
import { getMatchers } from "expect/build/jestMatchersObject";

return expect.extend({
  toMatchEntity(actual, expected) {
    const copy = ... // object manipulation
    return getMatchers().toMatchObject.call(this, copy, expected);
  },
});
```

I can't seem to do the same with Playwright [matchers](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/blob/6b0a7003c4e2d155fdb04301dd8e6b2e52646a85/packages/playwright-test/src/matchers/matchers.ts) as they're not exported in the [package.json](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/blob/6b0a7003c4e2d155fdb04301dd8e6b2e52646a85/packages/playwright-test/package.json#L11) for @playwright/test.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The first snippet *does* work, but `toHaveURL` returns `undefined` when successful and causes an error:

```
Error: Unexpected return from a matcher function.
Matcher functions should return an object in the following format:
  {message?: string | function, pass: boolean}
'undefined' was returned
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45745719/99021) on a similar question shows that you can handle the successful return value yourself, but must also handle the `not` condition. This updated example works as expected:

```
expect.extend({
  async toHaveDeploymentURL(page: Page, expected: string) {
    const matcher = this.isNot ? expect(page).not.toHaveURL : expect(page).toHaveURL;
    const fullyQualifiedPath = `https://deployments.company.com${expected}`;

    await matcher(fullyQualifiedPath);
    return {
      pass: true,
      message: () => `Deployment URL matched: ${expected}`
    };
  },
});
```

It's not clear to me why undefined is returned in successful cases, from looking at the [matcher source](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/blob/6b0a7003c4e2d155fdb04301dd8e6b2e52646a85/packages/playwright-test/src/matchers/matchers.ts). This does produce the nicely-formatted error one might expect in failure cases, though.